# how to display chart and graphs from gridview values

Tags: c#, excel, gridview

I would like to seek help again :) Is there a way to display chart value and graphs from gridview value?

What im trying to do this is upload an excel file and then display it on the gridview. (i was able to do this; i coded it with c#) but then i wish to display the chart values and graphs with the values fetched from the gridview. im currently using Microsoft Chart Tools.

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Nhoyti

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. If you want an easy integration you can look at [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/Charting/asp.xml). They have data, charting, and pivot tools that will work for WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and ASP.Net.

Here are some other resources:

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203246/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-image/Creating_Charts.aspx

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/gettingstartedstaticdata.html